# Is it rude to say commands or imperatives without saying please?

Tags: politeness

I've been wondering that for a long time. And if it is rude, then why does everyone say commands/imperatives without saying please? I personally phrase them into questions, or say "you have to","you need to","you can't"...and such. Does anyone else do that? Just me? I feel like everyone is bossy but me lol.

Also, I was wondering if saying "come on" is rude. It sounds mean or just negative when people do. Also when people say "let me" it also sounds mean-ish because it sounds like you are commanding permission from someone without them having any say.

Comment: I think this is really about manners and etiquette, which is not the same thing as language, and is therefore off topic. Two English speakers might consider different things rude. Also it's going to depend on circumstances. An army officer talking to a solider does not need to say 'please'. Whether your boss should say it depends on the relationship with the boss.

Comment: Ok. Do you have an answer for the second part?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etiguette.

Comment: Sorry I made it off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) it is about etiquette, not English and (b) even about etiquette, it is overly broad.

Comment: Sorry guys. I just needed this answered. And I saw a similar question so I thought it was ok. Sorry

Comment: Unless it is an emergency ("Duck!") or you are paying the person's salary, or you are a doctor ("Breathe in") don't give a competent adult an order.  Even if you are paying his salary, often it is better to say please.  There may be other exceptions.   As for "You have to", "you need to", "you can't", "you should", these are the same as orders.   I would suggest you go to Etiquette SE, except there isn't one.  Maybe Workplace SE if you are encountering this rudeness from your colleagues at work.  No need to apologize -- but your politeness is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Also for those phrases I meant, I rephrase commands like that because I thought they sound nicer like that.

Comment: Oh, what the heck.  Your question strikes a chord with me.   People take far too much interest in the minutiae of what other people do.  I wouldn't even say to a competent adult "You should stop smoking".

Comment: Sometimes saying "please" can be less polite, depending on how you say it.

Comment: @ab2: _People take far too much interest in the minutiae of what other people do_ Unless of course those other people can somehow benefit by it.

Comment: Oh my god @ab2, sorry I'm being such a crappy "stack exchange" person. This is my first time and I've really been thinking and confused about this stuff. I guess curiosity really did kill the cat.

Comment: No, you are fine.  You are on a learning curve.  Sometimes we can be pretty snarky.

Comment: Good manners also includes welcoming newcomers.  And etiquette usually does include language.  You can't separate one from the other.  I think this is an interesting linguistic question.  And it got me thinking:  When is please necessary?  If someone is jumping on your back, is it really necessary--or even better--to say "PLEASE get off"?  Should a sentry say "PLEASE halt"?  Do students respect a teacher more or less if he says PLEASE every time he gives an assignment?  Does he look stronger or weaker?  Should lovers say "PLEASE kiss me" all the time?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This community tends to prefer questions that are specific, and with some context thrown in so the question we think we're answering matches the question you're asking. Would you care to add a few sample commands / imperatives that you feel sound rude without the word *please*?

Comment: @Lawrence This is a language specific question. It's certainly looked at in both applied and theoretical linguistics. There are very wide language differences in this regard.

Comment: @Araucaria That broadness is the problem, and the question may be closed because of it. It may help to look at more focused examples, as I've asked the OP to provide (note to Pinkcat2244: politely but without an unquoted 'please').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are the 'Imperatives' used without 'please' or 'kindly' considered to be rude in the west?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210935/are-the-imperatives-used-without-please-or-kindly-considered-to-be-rude-in)

Answer (score 3):

Ricky is right.  "Good manners are part of grammar" or maybe grammar is part of good manners.

I voted to close this question, and I was wrong.  The OP is a polite person with a thoughtful question.

My answer is intended to apply only when the addressee is a competent adult,  although much of what I say may apply to children and/or incompetent adults.

As DJClayworth said an officer or an NCO in the armed services does not need to say please to soldiers.  In any situation where **instant** obedience is a matter of safety , **not** saying please is better. "Duck!" "Don't" (as in don't pat the bear); "Hands up!"  There are other situations in which please is unnecessary or even tiresome:  "You go first" (to a burdened person); "Open wide" (at the dentist.)

But this isn't what you are asking about.  Please softens the command or the request.  Please do X.  Please help me with Y.

Requests are often better as questions:  Can you please help me with Y?  Can you please do (or not do) X?  And, as Hot Licks says, please can be anything from polite to offensive, depending on intonation, body language, the tone of the rest of the sentence and what came before.

As for "you have to"; "you need to"; "you can't"; "you should".  It's OK if you are transmitting information, such as "You need to get a learner's permit before you can legally drive on a public road."  It's not OK if you are offering advice that you have not been asked for.

Don't offer advice on topic X unless you have been asked for advice on topic X.  Ask a question if you are truly worried (Have you seen a doctor about that cough?), and accept the person's answer without arguing about it.  You can say "You look tired" but not "you should go on a vacation" and certainly not "you should live a little."

"Come on" depends on intonation. An alternative, "are you ready" can be polite or rude, depending on tone.  "Let me..." depends on who you are talking to and what you are proposing to do. Open a door for a burdened young mother? OK.  Leap to help someone you consider a doddering wreck, but who considers himself perfectly capable, thank you.  Offensive.   And when the addressee says, thanks, but I can do it --  don't argue.

Off topic, maybe.

Comment: The question seems to be off-topic, but your answer is not.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make a request sound polite, even without turning it into a question.

> I'm afraid you have to move away from the door.
>
> I hope you don't mind getting away from that door.
>
> You'd look much prettier sitting in that chair with your legs upon the table than you do now, blocking that door.
>
> I know for a fact that you're not a dumb twit. Only dumb twits get between me and the door when I need to use it.

And so forth.

Good substitutes for ***Come on!***:

> Dedicatoin pays off.
>
> Diligence is a virtue, you know.
>
> Whoever gets there first will get a cookie.
>
> You'll never get married if you just keep standing around like that. Get a move on.
>
> Get on with it, Socrates.

Good substitutes for ***let me***:

> By your leave.
>
> May I, Your Grace?
>
> Allow me, I beg you.

Comment: Plenty of people would consider those much less than polite. The last one is pretty passive-aggressive, and if you said the third to a woman in a workplace you'd get yourself scheduled for sexual harassment training, never mind being considered rude.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I pay my employees too well for that.

Comment: Do you have an answer for the second part?

Comment: @user156814: Sure do.

Comment: Ok. What is it?

Comment: @user156814: They're in the edit.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of wanted an answer that's more...like  @DJClayworth than examples. But, I do appreciate what you've done. I feel bad I was off topic but I saw a similar question so I thought it was okay. So do you have explanations for both parts? And seriously, I am the only person who does say "come on" and "let me". And rephrases commands?

Comment: @user156814: I did, didn't I? Don't listen to anyone, good manners are part of grammar. They might close the question, but not because they're considerate, sympathetic, or affectionate people. And, yes, "Come on, _please_" is better than "You'll never get married if you just keep standing around like that. Get a move on."

Comment: Aw, Ricky, c'mon.

Comment: Oh no, I meant DOESN'T. Dang. Also, it won't let me edit my comment for some reason. I can't tell if it's supposed to be like that, or it's just me. This is my first time using this so I'm still learning.

Comment: @ab2: They gave me a bottle of very good XO cognac the other day. If you knew how good it is, you'd understand.

Comment: @user156814: A comment can't be edited once a new comment has been posted under it. It's a jungle out here.

Comment: Ok thanks. Edited my user too haha. I feel like I should have put the question,then numbered the extra stuff. I think I might redo this. Haha

Comment: I wouldn't use any of your alternate suggestions here in the US among my contemporaries, elders or younger people.  Where are you located Ricky? If you're blocking the door, I'd say, "Excuse me, you're blocking the door.", for "Come on!", I'd say "Can we please pick up the pace?" or "We need to hurry!", for "Let me", I'd use "Please" or simply "allow me".

Comment: Ricky, everything you have added here comes over as sarcastic. Sarcastic is not polite.

Comment: @DJClayworth: There are nuances.